# How do I hide fields conditionally?

Tags: 7, entities

i made my own module in my drupal 7 website to hide a boolean when its value is "0"
but something won't work

this is the code

```
   function MYTHEME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
if($node->content['field_members_only']['#items']['0']['value']=="0") {
                      hide($node->content['field_members_only']); 
                    }
}
```

what's wrong?
i think the conditional part is wrong
if i save the statement without the IF part it's working perfectly

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set access to FALSE.

```
function MYTHEME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if(isset($node->content['field_members_only']) && count($node->content['field_members_only']) && $node->content['field_members_only']['#items']['0']['value']=="0") {
    $node->content['field_members_only']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: as i said... the problem seems to be in the IF part... the statement works without it... the solution you suggest sets the website on HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$node->content['field_members_only']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

You might also want to consider making the if statement like this:

```
if(empty($node->content['field_members_only']['#items']['0']['value'])) {
```

From the php.net docs on [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), the following things are considered to be empty:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `$var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: YESS this works very well - if i change the conditional part also (THE IF).. 
thank you very much everybody... i didn't understand your solution thou... the empty function returns a TRUE when the field is set to 0 ?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information on the empty() function.